# How to display block on 100% of parent block HTML?

Tags: html, css

There is a such code with two div element:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item">
   <div class="hide"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item {
  position:relative;
  height:100%; // any height
}

.hide {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
  opacity:0.6;
  width:100%;
}
```

How to display `.hide` on full width and height of parent block `.item` not set fixed hright in px's

Comment: What exactly doesn't work about that? I have a fiddle where it adapts just fine to height and width of parent element.

Comment: Unless .item has a parent element with a defined height, the 100% height will still just be 0px tall.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following css rules to .hide:

```
.hide {
  ...
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: But if insdide this block exists other, how to center it?

Comment: You want to center the .hide block or the other one?